# Confusing behavior of ifnull() in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table **'customer_master'** and some values in it.

```
CREATE TABLE customer_master(
    CUSTOMER_NUMBER VARCHAR(6),
    FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(30),
    middlename VARCHAR(30),
    lastname VARCHAR(30),
    CUSTOMER_CITY VARCHAR(15),
    CUSTOMER_CONTACT_NO VARCHAR(10),
    occupation VARCHAR(10),
    CUSTOMER_DATE_OF_BIRTH DATE,
    CONSTRAINT customer_custid_pk PRIMARY KEY (CUSTOMER_NUMBER)
);
```

I wanted to find `customer_number`,`firstname`, `middlename` and `lastname` fom the above table with condition that for those customers who dont have middle name then "null" value in `middlename` should be replaced by `lastname`.

So i thought why not use `ifnull(middlename,lastname)` here and when i used it then i got some interesting results.

> Before using ifnull()

If i dont use ifnull then my result table looks like this.

```
select customer_number, firstname, middlename, lastname from customer_master;
```

[image]

> After using ifnull()

```
select customer_number ,firstname, ifnull(middlename, lastname) as 'Middle_Name' , lastname from customer_master;
```

[image]

**I expected that all null values in** `middlename` **will be replaced by** `lastname`, but it did not happened why? and why only some `middlename` rows got the `lastname` values not all?
Any explanation ?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c742b/3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you imported the data, perhaps the `NULL` is really `'NULL'`, so try:

```
select . . .,
       (case when ltrim(rtrim(middlename)) = 'NULL' or middlename is null
             then lastname
             else middlename
        end) as middlename
```